# Processing the real-time last line in a currently being written text file

Tags: bash, file-io

I have a text file which is in fact open and does logging activities performed by process P1 in the system. I was wondering how I can get the real time content of the last line of this file in a bash script and do "echo" a message, say "done was seen", if the line equals to "done".

Comment: Have you looked into `tail -f yourfile` ?

Comment: Yes. It does not return me the current last line until the process gets finished (log file gets closed).

Comment: You need to make sure your process `P1` is not buffering its output for `tail -f` to be effective.

Comment: Well, if `tail -f` is not showing anything until the file is closed, either your output is getting buffered or your process only outputs at the end. If you call `cat` instead of `tail` on the log file, is anything listed at all on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
tail -f log.txt | sed -n '/^done$/q' && echo done was seen
```

**Explanation:**

- `tail -f` [will output appended data as the file grows](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)
- `sed -n '/^done$/q'` will exit when a line containing only `done` is encountered, ending the command pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep -q -m 1 done && echo done was seen
```

The `-m` flag to `grep` means "exit after N matches", and the `&&` ensures that the `echo` statement will only be done on a successful exit from `grep`.